# hmvc codeigniter

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, module, hmvc

I have learned the basics of codeigniter and now learning the modules.

**My problem :**  I have made two folders inside the modules folder, `first_module` and `second_module`.

In the `first_module` inside the controller my code :

```
<?php
    class First_module extends MX_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('first_module_view');            
    }
}
?>
```

`first_module_view` page code :

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1> hey this is first module </h1>
    <?php 
        echo Modules::run('second_module/second_module');
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

`second_module` controller page :

```
<?php
class Second_module extends MX_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('second_module_view');
    }
}
?>
```

`second_module_view` page:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1> hey this is second module </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to partially view the second module view in the `first_module` view using the second_module's controller, but that is not working.
Individually both codes are working fine but `Modules::run()` doesn't seems to work.

Am I missing something?

Comment: just to confirm can you tell is Modules::$locations array set in config ?

Comment: Umm.. I ve set 
`$config['modules_locations'] = array(
    APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/',
);` in the config file

Comment: Solved... :)
I was not including index in the `echo Modules::run('second_module/second_module');`

It is executing correctly in the code :-
`echo Modules::run('second_module/second_module\index');`

Comment: Oh, you really do not want to call one controller from the other. That is why it is called modular separation. You can share models and views by referencing them with the other module (first_module/first_module_view.php). You will have all sorts of headaches if you start calling one controller from another.

Comment: I tend to agree by Thom, it's why MVC was created in the first place to separate stuff... anyways, if you absolutely need this, do not put html, head and body tags into the second view, since that would generate a semantically incorrect website

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045226/codeigniter-load-controller-within-a-controller-hmvc

Answer (score 1):

I am aware that you have found your solution and this does not answer the exact question that you asked, however, I would usually do something like that in this way:

```
       <?php
            class First_module extends MX_Controller {
            public function index()
            {
                 $content = array();

                //send content array to 2nd view and return everything as a string to be added as content to the first view

               $content["second_view"] = $this->load->view('second_module_view',$content,true);

               $this->load->view('first_module_view',$content);            
            }
        }
        ?>
```

First module view then becomes:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1> hey this is first module </h1>
    <?php 
        echo $second_view;
    ?>
</body>
```

I've not worked with modules specifically, however this is how I would do it with controllers and views. I would do what I can to limit the calls to models and modules from within the view. Just pass in variables generated in the controller from your models.

Comment: Nice, this appears to be the proper way to implement an HMVC (instead of simple MVC) page with CodeIgniter.