# CodeIgniter load controller within a controller HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, partial-views, codeigniter-2, hmvc

I'm using http://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template/ for the templates
and I trying to load other controller view to actual view as a partial.
My main problem is that I cant append meta data (javascripts, css) from other controller to the main controller.

**application/core/MY_Loader.php**

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function controller( $sController ) {
        global $RTR;

        // Parse the sController string ex: demo/index
        $aControllerData = explode( '/', $sController );

        $sMethod = !empty( $aControllerData[1] )
            ? $aControllerData[1]
            : 'index'
        ;
        $sController = !empty( $aControllerData[0] )
            ? $aControllerData[0]
            : $RTR->default_controller
        ;

        $sClass = ucfirst( $sController );

        $sPath = APPPATH . 'controllers/';

        if ( !file_exists( $sPath . $sController . '.php' ) || class_exists( $sClass, FALSE ) ) {

            set_status_header( 503 );
            exit( 'Unable to locate the specified class: '. ucfirst( $sController ).'.php' );
        }
        $this->file( $sPath . $sController . '.php' );
        $sClass = new $sClass;

        if ( !method_exists( $sClass, $sMethod ) ) {
            set_status_header( 503 );
            exit( 'There is no Method: ' . $sMethod . ' in Class: '. ucfirst( $sController ).'.php' );
        }
        $aArguments = func_get_args();
        return call_user_func_array( array( $sClass, $sMethod ), array_slice( $aArguments, 1));
    }

}


/* End of file MY_Loader.php */
/* Location: ./controllers/MY_Loader.php */
```

**application/controllers/demo.php**

```
<?php if ( !defined( 'BASEPATH' ) ) {
    exit( 'No direct script access allowed' );
}

class Demo extends CI_Controller
{

    function index() {

        $this->load->controller('welcome');
        $this->template->set_partial('footer', 'partials/footer')->build('demo');
    }
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./controllers/demo.php */
```

**application/controllers/welcome.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Loaded welcome controller';
        $this->template->title('Welcome');
        $this->template->append_metadata('<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>');
        $this->template->set_partial('footer', 'partials/footer')->build('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

After going to the url localhost/demo i got interface with partials and everything looks good, but I see that there are some libraries loaded too many times in my logs.

```
DEBUG - 2012-10-24 08:02:16 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-10-24 08:02:16 --> User Agent Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-10-24 08:02:16 --> Template Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-10-24 08:02:16 --> Controller Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-10-24 08:02:16 --> File loaded: /home/www/application/controllers/welcome.php
DEBUG - 2012-10-24 08:02:16 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-10-24 08:02:16 --> User Agent Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-10-24 08:02:16 --> Template Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-10-24 08:02:16 --> Controller Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-10-24 08:02:16 --> File loaded: /home/www/application/themes/default/views/partials/footer.php
DEBUG - 2012-10-24 08:02:16 --> File loaded: /home/www/application/views/welcome_message.php
DEBUG - 2012-10-24 08:02:16 --> File loaded: /home/www/application/themes/default/views/layouts/main.php
DEBUG - 2012-10-24 08:02:16 --> Helper loaded: inflector_helper
DEBUG - 2012-10-24 08:02:16 --> File loaded: /home/www/application/themes/default/views/partials/footer.php
DEBUG - 2012-10-24 08:02:16 --> File loaded: /home/www/application/views/demo.php
DEBUG - 2012-10-24 08:02:16 --> File loaded: /home/www/application/themes/default/views/layouts/main.php
DEBUG - 2012-10-24 08:02:16 --> Final output sent to browser
```

I was trying to use HMVC but there was the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution at https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/1818
There is a real HMVC and it works. I hope that this will be included in upcoming CodeIgniter release.

My test results are shown in the images.
controllers/demo.php

```
class Demo extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->controller('welcome');
        $this->load->view('demo');
    }
}
```

[image: Results]
<sub>(source: [github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/1818))</sub>