# Loading A Controller Within Controller Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to know if it is possible to make a `MY_Controller` that will let me do what I describe below in my controller file.

Just so I can load controllers like this:

```
<?php 

class Home extends CI_Controller {

public function index(){
$data['column_left'] = $this->load->controllers('common/column_left');
$data['column_right'] = $this->load->controllers('common/column_right');
$data['content_top'] = $this->load->controllers('common/content_top');
$data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controllers('common/content_bottom');
$data['footer'] = $this->load->controllers('common/footer');
$data['header'] = $this->load->controllers('common/header');

if (file_exists('/template/common/home.tpl')) {
    $this->load->view('/template/common/home.tpl', $data));
} else {
    $this->load->view('default/template/common/home.tpl', $data));
}       
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate to [Here][1] or [Here][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045226/codeigniter-load-controller-within-a-controller-hmvc
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045226/codeigniter-load-controller-within-a-controller-hmvc

By the way! Try HMVC

Comment: I have use HMVC Before NOT what I am after.